# How to increase shipping cost according to quantity

Tags: prestashop

I am currently setting up the shipping settings for my site [www.lordswoods.co.uk](http://www.lordswoods.co.uk)

I have set up two carriers

1. Yodel- maximum package weight 30kg (carrier range 1kg to 75kg) price £7.75
2. Pallet track - for all total orders above 75kg

When I order a 1 x 20kg item such as pro master 5 - economy green. The shipping price in the cart is £7.75 as it should be. However when I increase the quantity to two, the shipping price stays the same at £7.75, whereas I want it to to be £7.75 per item until 75 kg is reached.

e.g., 3 x promaster 5 should equal £23.25 (3 x 7.75)

How do I set this up?

Comment: What does your shipping setup look like now? Which weight ranges have you defined? And what prices do you have for each range?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the shipping cost to all the products separately instead of adding it in the carrier. That way your shipping charges will increase for each item added to the cart.